# Why did no one answer the distress signal of the Resistance?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

In the beginning of *The Last Jedi*, the Resistance evacuated from their base on D'Qar, just before it was annihilated by the First Order. Then, throughout the movie, they tried to run away from the enemy ships and find a new base for themselves, in order to call for assistance.

> **Leia Organa:** We need to find a new base.
>
> **Larma D'Acy:** One with enough power to get a distress signal to our
>   allies scattered in the Outer Rim.

In the end, the remaining Resistance survivors landed on the planet Crait and were able to send out a distress call, though there was no answer from anyone.

> **Kaydel Connix:** Our distress signal's been received at multiple points,
>   but no response.
>
> **Larma D'Acy:** They've heard us, but no one's coming.

Was the signal actually heard by the allies? Why didn't they answer? Were they already controlled by the First Order, like the opening crawl stated:

> Having decimated the peaceful Republic, Supreme Leader Snoke now
>   deploys his merciless legions to seize military control of the galaxy.

Comment: Do you know there's nothing about this in the novelization or other media?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the (canon) [*Star Wars: Battles that Changed the Galaxy*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Battles_that_Changed_the_Galaxy) factbook, the lack of response from the Resistance's allies breaks down into two main categories; that the First Order managed to jam most of their communications with the outside world, and that First Order agents had begun systematically assassinating or imprisoning known Resistance and Rebellion allies and sympathisers on dozens of planets, safe in the knowledge that the New Republic was now no longer in position to retaliate for this provocative action.

> Organa found temporary refuge with Resistance sympathizers on Ryloth,
> and discovered why her plea from Crait had gone unheeded: the First
> Order had not only blocked communications but also targeted those who
> might have responded — former soldiers, pilots, and strategists, old
> rebels and Imperials alike — assassinating some and imprisoning others.